# How can I read and find specific information in a txt file and compare it to strings unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game similar to scrabble in unity c#. The unity version I am using is 2019.4. I have a txt file which contains 58110 words. I would like to have a unity script which sees if a string is contained in the txt (The string is a word inputted by the player). I have looked up a few tutorials but none have been able to offer what I have been looking for and I am to beginner to try do it on my own (sorry) so what is the best way to do this? (I haven't tried anything so far because the results of the tutorials have not been satisfactory and of course I have no idea how to do it on my own).

Comment: _"I have a txt file which contains 58110 words"_ - how are they separated? By line? All on one line with some kind of delimiter character?

Comment: They are separated by lines

Answer (score 1):

Assuming unity has access to these calls. You can just use `File.ReadAllines` and then convert it to a `HashSet`, use `Contains` to do a fast lookup.

```
var hashSet = File
     .ReadAllLines("SomeFileName")
     .ToHashSet();
   // if you want case insensitivity
   //.ToHashSet(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

if (hashSet .Contains(SomeUserInputedString))
   Debug.Log("You Won");
```

If unity doesn't have `ToHashSet`, you can just use its constructor

```
var hashSet = new HashSet(File.ReadAllLines("SomeFileName")) ;
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[File.ReadAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0)

> Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array,
> and then closes the file.

[Enumerable.ToHashSet Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=net-5.0)

> Creates a `HashSet<T>` from an `IEnumerable<T>` using the comparer to
> compare keys.

[HashSet.Contains(T) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=net-5.0)

> Determines whether a HashSet object contains the specified element.

Comment: Afaik Unity currently is limited to `.NET Framework 4.7.1` so `ToHashSet` most probably won't "exist" yet, so constructor it is ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to accomplish what you've asked for:

```
public class Words : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TextAsset words;
    [SerializeField] private bool useCase = false;
    private HashSet<string> wordHashes = new HashSet<string> ( );

    void Start()
    {
        // Creates the hashset data set at the start of the game.
        var words = this.words.text.Split ( new [ ] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
        for ( int i = 0, count = words.Length; i < count; i++ )
        {
            Debug.Log ( $"Read {words[i]} from the words list." );
            wordHashes.Add ( useCase ? words [ i ] : words [ i ].ToLower ( ) );
        }
        Debug.Log ( $"Hashset contains One : {Contains ( "One" )}" );
    }

    public bool Contains ( string word )
    {
        return wordHashes.Contains ( useCase ? word : word.ToLower ( ) );
    }
}
```

It makes use of the `TextAsset` asset that will be packaged with your game when compiled. At the appropriate time, you can parse the `words` `TextAsset`, pulling the words out and into a `HashSet`. Including a `Contains` method makes it easy to then query whether or not a word was included in the `words` list.

One optimisation would be to serialise the actual HashSet data after all of the words had been read in. It saves having to create the HashSet at the beginning of the game that *might* take a noticeable length of time when the game is restarted. Generating the hash at runtime also creates a little bit of Garbage as well, which will be cleared at some stage. The HashSet data could be stored into something like a ScriptableObject, from an Editor script. But, that's not what was asked of in the question, and is just a preference of mine.

[Here's](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html) the Unity docs regarding `TextAsset`.